# On Mac I can't get the circle for proportional editing to appear

Tags: modeling, mesh, proportional-editing

On my Mac, I can't get the zoom circle for vertex selection to appear on proportional editing.

Not sure if there's a setting in Blender I'm missing or something with my mouse settings, but the zoom circle does not appear when I click proportional editing to select vertices. Nothing online addresses this issue. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Might be too large...?

Comment: prop edit influence is larger than your field of view.

Answer (score 0):

- Enter Edit Mode;
- Turn on *Proportional Editing*;
- Select a desired point;
- Grab with  <kbd>G</kbd>;
- Click the selected point again, and you will see a pop-up menu;
- Set the proportional size **between the major radius and minor radius** of the object.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same answer more than once, if you find two identical questions please mark them as duplicates so they can be linked instead.